# is it possible to have static variable inside a rebol function?

Tags: rebol

This shows how to have a static variable inside an object or context:
http://www.mail-archive.com/list@rebol.com/msg04764.html

But the scope is too large for some needs, is it possible to have a static variable inside an object function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rebol 3, use a **closure** (or CLOS) rather than a **function** (or FUNC).

In Rebol 2, fake it by having a block that contains your static values, eg :

```
f: func [
   /local sb
][
     ;; define and initialise the static block
 sb: [] if 0 = length? sb [append sb 0]

     ;; demonstate its value persists across calls
 sb/1: sb/1 + 1
 print sb
 ]

    ;; sample code to demonstrate function
 loop 5 [f]
 == 1
 == 2
 == 3
 == 4
 == 5
```

Comment: Clever, thanks. (I'm still using R2 as R3 doesn't seem to work with my pc)

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use `FUNCTION/WITH`.  This makes the function generator take a third parameter, which defines a persistent object that is used as the *"self"*:

```
accumulate: function/with [value /reset] [
    accumulator: either reset [
        value
    ] [
        accumulator + value
    ]
] [
    accumulator: 0
]
```

To use it:

```
>> accumulate 10
== 10

>> accumulate 20
== 30

>> accumulate/reset 0
== 0

>> accumulate 3
== 3

>> accumulate 4
== 7
```

You may also want to look at [my FUNCS function](http://www.fm.vslib.cz/~ladislav/rebol/funcs.r).

Comment: Was fixing the FUNCT name correction, and [added the accumulator usage example](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3271463/2).  *(pursuant to the policy of it [being okay to add examples to answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20447/))*  No endorsement by @Ladislav express or implied.  :-)