# Rebol: why get-access-modifier is called twice whereas It should be called only once

Tags: rebol

When typing in rebol console

```
do read http://askcodegeneration.com/csharp/simple-class/
```

I get get-access-modifier called twice:

```
Access modifier:
1. private: member can be accessed only by code in the same class
2. protected: member can be accessed only by code in the same class or in a derived  class
3. internal: member can be accessed only by code in the same assembly
4. public: member can be accessed by code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it choice (by default 1): 
Access modifier:
1. private: member can be accessed only by code in the same class
2. protected: member can be accessed only by code in the same class or in a derived  class
3. internal: member can be accessed only by code in the same assembly
4. public: member can be accessed by code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it choice (by default 1):
```

Whereas it is only mentioned once in the source code:

```
append fields-template-output form reduce [
    (to-word get-access-modifier) field-layout
]
```

I really can't see why, can you ?

[Original code here (Internet Archive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20090914011526/http://askcodegeneration.com/csharp/simple-class/)

Comment: It is confusing that you are having that URL provide formatted code to browsers and then plain source to Rebol.  Is there a reason for that?

Comment: The code-block thing and having so much of your code in string format seems unnecessary, the header's not in the code that's executing, etc.  I've put a few things in a copy of your code here in hopes it will assist your Rebol Fu: http://pastebin.ca/1893154

Comment: There's no two versions of code one in html and one in rebol, it's the same source code. When you execute there is a pre-processing that get only the rebol code. It's not confusing at all, it's a feature that I want: I want to code and document at the same time and be able to split into modules without resorting to several files and all at the same url so that I don't have to remember or retype another url but just copy and paste what I see.

Comment: Because I have potentiel hundreds of these kind of scripts on multiple domains, it is important not to lose time on what's the url. I search on blog, copy and paste the url in rebol console and I'm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  There is only one call to it, but it's inside of a `foreach`.  Your default is two fields, so you get asked twice.  Enter more, you'll get asked more.

While you could (and probably should) do the obvious thing of saving it in a variable, Rebol has other ways.  For instance you could `compose` the block of code:

```
foreach field-layout fields-layout COMPOSE/DEEP [
    append fields-template-output  "        "
    append fields-template-output  form reduce [
        to-word (get-access-modifier) field-layout
    ]
    append fields-template-output  ";"
    append fields-template-output  newline
]
```

The composition runs once, looks deep for the parentheses in the block, and evaluates the code.  (Kind of how parse does when it sees parentheses).  The rest is left alone.  So the block with the substitutions done is what's passed into FOREACH to run the loop.

Just a nuance of how you *could* have a call that appears to be inside a loop and yet is executed only once.  I wouldn't suggest using it for something like this.

What I *would* suggest is studying making things less redundant in your code, by learning some more Rebol primitives like REJOIN...which builds a series out of a block.  The series type will match whatever the first type it sees is (or a string if the first element is not a series):

```
modifier: get-access-modifier ;-- called only once, stored in variable

foreach field-layout fields-layout [
    append fields-template-output rejoin [
        "        "
        (to-string modifier)
        field-layout
        ";"
        newline
    ]
]
```

Comment: ...and you know what I'm going to say about paring down code to generate a minimal test case!  You will usually solve simple mistakes like this on your own if you do!

Comment: Oops stupid of me, I'm not accustomed to code professionally any more and sometimes basics just escape me :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I have used static var to detect that it is executed only once (thanks to Sunanda tips [is it possible to have static variable inside a rebol function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860925/is-it-possible-to-have-static-variable-inside-a-rebol-function) ).

```
ask-params: function [config-file [file!] default-class-name default-fields] [
  ;config-file: %askcodegeneration.com/csharp/simple-class/simple-class.params.txt

  either value? 'class-name [
     ans: ask rejoin ["class name" " (by default " class-name ")" ": "]
     if ans <> "" [class-name: ans]
  ][
     class-name: default-class-name
     ans: ask rejoin [{class name (default "} class-name {"): }]
     if ans <> "" [class-name: ans]
  ]

  either exists? it: config-file [
      params-block: copy load it
  ][
      params-block: []
  ]

  either res: find params-block class-name [
      fields: pick res 2
      print [ class-name "found in" it]
  ][

      fields: default-fields
      ans: ask rejoin [{fields (by default } {"} fields {"} {): }]
      if ans <> "" [fields: ans]

      new-param: reduce [
      mold class-name
      mold fields
      ]

      either not exists? config-file [
          create-directory "askcodegeneration.com/csharp/simple-class/"
          write/append config-file reform new-param
      ][
          write/append config-file reform [newline new-param]
      ]

  ]
  append ret-value: [] class-name
  append ret-value fields

  ret-value
]
```